# Использование нескольких строк подключения

Tags: c#, asp.net

Имеется старый проект на asp.net (web forms). Появилась необходимость добавить вторую строку подключения (в web.config) и через select тег переключать, когда необходимо запросы выполнить к другой БД. Как это лучше и правильнее сделать подскажите? Где хранить значение выбранной БД? Я попробовал делать через куки:

Из Js отправляю на сервер данные о выбранном подключении и записываю в свойство:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = System.Web.Script.Services.ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string SetConnection(string connectionName)
{
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionName))
    {        
        Handlers.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionName].ConnectionString;
    }
    return Handlers.ConnectionString;
}
```

В Handlers.cs:

```
private static string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["nameConn"].Value].ConnectionString;

public static string ConnectionString
{
    get 
    {              
        return connectionString;
    }
    set
    {
        connectionString = value;
    }                              
}
```

Далее обращаюсь к свойству ConnectionString из других методов и делаю запрос к БД (new SqlConnection(ConnectionString)). Это работает, но через какое то время (например через 2ч) обновлю страницу и данные не приходят с sql сервера, пишет "System.TypeInitializationException" Message : "Инициализатор типа "ProjectSO.Handlers" выдал исключение. В dev режиме не могу воспроизвести проблему..

Вот метод из которого обращаюс к БД:

```
public static List<object> GetData()
{
    List<object> result = new List<object>();           
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"exec dbo.getData", conn);
        
    SqlDataReader reader = null;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        if (conn.State.ToString() == "Open")
        {
            reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                   
                   result.Add(new DynaTreeNode()
                   {                               
                        key = reader.GetValue(1).ToString(),
                        title = reader.GetValue(2).ToString(),
                        children = null
                   });                                                  
                   
                }
            }
        }
     }       
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         WriteToEventLog(ex, "GetData");
     }
     finally
     {
         if (reader != null) { reader.Close(); }
         conn.Close();
     }

     return result;
    
}
```

Comment: Упал конструктор класса ProjectSO.Handlers, смотрите трассировку стека.

Comment: @aepot, смотрел. Вызывается метод который подгружает данные из БД. В нем создается новое подключение к бд через обращение к свойству new SqlConnection(ConnectionString), строка указанная в трассировке стека указывает на  key = reader.GetValue(1).ToString() - но какая тут проблема не понятна.

Comment: В этой строке в целом может быть только одна проблема, `reader.GetValue(1)` вернул `null`, ну или сам `reader` `null`. А вообще работа с сетью или другими внешними источниками данных в конструкторе - плохая история. Конструктор должен инициализировать свойства класса, а не запускать активные процессы. Задача конструктора - рабочий экземпляр класса, в котором функционируют все методы корректно, согласно описанному в документации поведению. Все остальное надо выполнять в методах, вызывамых отдельно от конструктора. Создание экземпляров для работы с бд - ок, а вот само подключение - нет.

Comment: Так же убедитесь, что `IDisposable` объекты для работы с БД уничтожаются своевременно.

Comment: @aepot, спасибо. А как в моем случае лучше определять строку подключения?

Comment: Строка подключения тут вообще не при чем. Строка подключения - это просто текст.

Comment: @aepot, имеется ввиду а где я "запустил активный процесс" в конструкторе?

Comment: Начали подключаться к базе и получать данные. Исходите из соображения, что конструктор должен выполняться мгновенно.

Comment: @aepot, добавил метод вверху. Из него я подключаюсь к БД.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Всё, понял, падает здесь `ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["nameConn"].Value].ConnectionString;` то есть либо `ConnectionStrings` не содержит то что возвращает `HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["nameConn"].Value`, либо падает само вычисление этого выражения, унесите в настоящий конструктор и оберните в `try-catch`.

```
public string ConnectionString { get; set; }

public Handlers()
{
    try
    {
        ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["nameConn"].Value].ConnectionString;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WriteToEventLog(ex, "ConnectionString");
    }
}
```

`static` убрать.

Таким образом можно узнать, что же на самом деле произошло, а убирание `static` может реально вылечить проблему.

`GetData()` - тоже убрать статику.

```
public List<DynaTreeNode> GetData()
{
    List<DynaTreeNode> result = new List<DynaTreeNode>();           
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"exec dbo.getData", conn))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    result.Add(new DynaTreeNode()
                    {                               
                        key = reader.GetValue(1).ToString(),
                        title = reader.GetValue(2).ToString(),
                        children = null
                    });                                                  
                }
            }
        }
    }       
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        WriteToEventLog(ex, "GetData");
    }

    return result;
    
}
```

Создавайте экземпляр `var handlers = new Handlers()` и через экземпляр работайте. Если потребуется, сделайте синглтон, но никак не статику.

Comment: спасибо, попробую, отмечу в любом случае как ответ. Там кстати все методы в классе Handlers статичные и из других мест вызов идет не посредственно через прямое обращение Handlers.NameMethod. Я так понимаю надо везде статику убрать и сначала создавать, как вы сказали новый экземпляр класса и через эту переменную обращаться к нужному методу

Comment: @Odyssey верно, для начала такой способ должен сработать. В будущем для экономии ресурсов можете синглтон сделать.